# Explain me how OpenGL stores variables in SSBO

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have encountered a strange problem with variables in SSBO.

I have the following struct with variables that is passed to SSBO:

```cpp
struct {
    glm::mat4 modelViewMatrix{1};
    ViewRenderTypeEnum type{};
    glm::vec4 colorStatic{};
} modelSettings;
```

Where,

- **ViewRenderTypeEnum** is enum describing the behavior of the shader program and defined as

```cpp
enum ViewRenderTypeEnum { VIEW_RENDER_TEXT, VIEW_RENDER_CLASSIC, VIEW_RENDER_GRADIENT };
```

- **modelViewMatrix** is model transformation matrix
- **colorStatic** is color that used only with VIEW_RENDER_CLASSIC

Here are the frame events from NVIDIA Nsight:

[image: events of a frame from NVIDAI Nsight]

And here are the vertex and fragment shaders:

```c
//Vertex shader
#version 430
const int TEXT = 0;
const int GUI_SIMPLE_COLOR  = 1;
const int GUI_GRADIENT_COLOR = 2;

layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertexIn;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 uvIn;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 colorsIn;

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer ProgramWideSettings {
    mat4 viewProjMatrix;
};

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer ModelWideSettings {
    mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    int type;
    vec4 colorStatic;
};

out vec2 uvVS;
out vec4 colorVS;

void main() {
    gl_Position = viewProjMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexIn, 0.0, 1.0);
    switch (type){
        case TEXT:{
            uvVS = uvIn;
            colorVS = colorStatic;
            break;
        }
        case GUI_SIMPLE_COLOR:{
            colorVS = colorStatic;
            break;
        }
        case GUI_GRADIENT_COLOR:{
            colorVS = colorsIn;
            break;
        }

    }
//colorVS = colorStatic;//Debug output
}

//Fragment shader
#version 430

const int TEXT = 0;
const int GUI_SIMPLE_COLOR  = 1;
const int GUI_GRADIENT_COLOR = 2;

layout(std430, binding = 1) buffer ModelWideSettings {
    mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    int type;
vec4 colorStatic;
};

uniform sampler2D text;

in vec2 uvVS;
in vec4 colorVS;

out vec4 colorOut;

void main() {
    switch (type){
        case TEXT:{
            vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, uvVS).r);
            colorOut = colorVS * sampled;
            break;
        }
        default :{

            colorOut = colorVS;
        }

    }
//colorOut = colorVS;//Debug output
}
```

When trying to render with this order of variables in shaders and struct, Nsight shows that there is no colorStatic variable in SSBO:

[image]

The geometry (two triangles) is not visible in this case, but Nsight reports that it is actually displayed. But if I hard-code the white color in the vertex shader in the last line, I can see two white triangles.

If I reorder variables in the shaders and in the struct this way

```cpp
struct {
   glm::mat4 modelViewMatrix{1};
   glm::vec4 colorStatic{};
   ViewRenderTypeEnum type{};
} modelSettings;
```

then Nsight will show me correct SSBO content

[image]

and I will see my triangles.

So, I have several questions:
Is the order of variables really important? If so, which order I must use and what happens in OpenGL when I change it? If not, could you help me fix this strange behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order is relevant in the sense as the order in the declaration will also define the order of the fields in memory.

Nsight doesn't show your `colorStatic` field in the first case as it is not present in the buffer. Using your original layout, as per `std430` alignment rules, your struct is 96 bytes in memory, but the buffer you provide is only 84 bytes, as a result the last member isn't even provided in the memory and you're running into *undefined behavior*.

If you re-order the elements as you did, the std430 alignment rules will not add any further padding (assuming your enum type is compatible to a 32bit integer, as @datenwolf pointed out) and the struct will be 84 bytes in memory.

This is just another instance of the typical case of ignoring what `std430` actually means...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. _This is just another instance of the typical case of ignoring what std430 actually means..._ Sorry, this is my first experience with SSBO. I had previously read the Khronos OpenGL wiki about SSBO, but didn't quite understand how std140 and std430 work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The size of an `enum` is determined either by

- whatever smallest integer type will fit the largest value of the `enum`

or

- by explicit specification of the underlying type with `enum class name : type`

Your `enum` is of the first kind and likely smaller than an `int`. Either use an explicitly sized integer, like `int32_t` or a `class enum … : int32_t` so that the host and GPU side use the same struct layout.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to use `int` as the underlying type, but the size of the struct was the same, so I found it superfluous to write it in the snippet